# How can I get a Google spreadsheet cell or range reference dynamically?

Tags: google-sheets

I can explicitly reference cell `G42` or range `A42:G42`.

But what if I need something dynamic?
For example: I want to write an expression in cell `G200`, which would calculate the average of cells `A42:G42`, without explicitly writing `A42:G42`, but by taking the value of cell `G201`, which is 42, finding "`G`" by seeing in which column the current cell is and finding "`A`" by going seven columns back from column `G`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using `indirect` in R1C1 notation. The following formula matches your situation:

```
=indirect("R" & G201 & "C" & column()-6 & ":R" & G201 & "C" & column(), False)
```

The range is described by a string formed by concatenating

```
R<row number>C<column number>:R<row number>C<column number>
```

The row numbers are taken from G201, the column numbers are computed with the `column()` function that returns the column number of current cell. (By the way, A is 6 places to the left of G, not seven)